# Changing string text color

Tags: android

```
<string name="no_city"><font color='#FF0000'><b>Please select your location under Preferences in the menu</b></font> </string>
```

```java
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.contents);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.contents);

    ChangeLog cl = new ChangeLog(this);
    if (cl.firstRun())
        cl.getFullLogDialog().show();


    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    TextView text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);

    Resources res = getResources();
    String text = String.format(res.getString(R.string.no_city));
    CharSequence styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);

    text1.setText(prefs.getString("listPref",res.getString(R.string.no_city)));
```

I am trying to change the color of the text in the no_city string. I have the way I have the string entered up top and the java underneath. Ihav etried both the hex and the color name, and neither have worked. I have found this information on Google's developer site on how to reference the changes, it compiles fine, but the text is still white. I am using the string with a list preference as what shows as default if nothing is selected from the list. When a user makes a selection, the text needs to be white, so I can not change the entire text view color in the xml or in the java file. I have a felling I am missing something small or I am overlooking something, but I can not track it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify SPANNABLE as the BufferType when you set the text on the view:

```
text1.setText(styledText, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `text1.setTextColor()` ???

Answer (score 0):

you can use directly :

```
txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.no_city));
```

refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29)